# Issues using Toggle and FadeIn Simultaneously

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fact</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    #fact_box {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      color: blue;
      border-style: dotted;
      position: relative;
    }


    .replace {
      height: 200px;
      width:  200px;
    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#fact_box").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle(function () {
            $(".box_image").fadeOut().replaceWith('<div class="replace">' + "Superman Returns" + '</div>');
        }, function () {
            $(".replace").fadeIn().replaceWith('<img class="box_image" src="http://www.pxleyes.com/images/tutorials/ext//4b757ff47d682.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/>')
        });
    });
});

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="fact_box">
  <img class="box_image" src="http://www.pxleyes.com/images/tutorials/ext//4b757ff47d682.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi, I need some help in debugging the JQuery code. When I click on the image, I want it to fadeout and be replaced by a div element. When I click on the div element next, I want it to be replaced by the image. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is currently going wrong?

Comment: You are using toggle() wrong, see http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Stefan, I'm referring to this book JQuery in Action and it gives another syntax of toggle which is not mentioned in the link you shared.


toggle(listener1,listener2, ...)
Establishes the passed functions as a circular list of click event handlers on all elements of the 
wrapped set. The handlers are called in order on each subsequent click event.
Parameters
listenerN (Function) One or more functions that serve as the click event handlers for 
subsequent clicks. 
Returns
The wrapped set.

Comment: @Pekka Single click nothing happens. Double Click, it fades out. But doesn't fadeIn after any number of clicks henceforth

Comment: @Cafecorridor It's possible that the book is referring to a jQuery plugin that provides a new implementation of the `.toggle()` function.

Comment: @Anthony Here's the link to this function. - http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @Cafecorridor Well, seems I'm less awake than I thought and managed to completely miss that in the docs. Good to know.

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem. Here's the JQuery code that works - 

$(function() {  
      $("#fact_box").toggle( function() {
      $(".box_image").fadeOut( function() { $(this).replaceWith('<div class="replace">' + "Superman Returns"+'</div>'); }); }, function() {
   $(".replace").fadeIn( function() { $(this).replaceWith('<img class="box_image" src="video.png" width="200px" height="200px"/>'); });  }); 
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining of your `toggle()` methods is incorrect, as well as the fact you have both a `click()` handler with a `toggle()` iside it - try this instead:

```
$("#fact_box").toggle(
    function() {
        $(".box_image", this).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div class="replace">Superman Returns</div>');
        });
    },   
    function() {
        $(".replace", this).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div class="box_image"></div>');
        });
    }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rtYRR/)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn´t bind both [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), try this;

```
$(function () {
    $("#fact_box").toggle(function () {
          //console.log('even');
            $(".box_image").fadeOut().replaceWith('<div class="replace">' + "Superman Returns" + '</div>');
        }, function () {
          //console.log('odd');
            $(".replace").fadeIn().replaceWith('<img class="box_image" src="http://www.pxleyes.com/images/tutorials/ext//4b757ff47d682.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/>')
        });
});
```

You should probably use callback functions for the animation to finish before you replace the element.